Django Static Files Not Loading Correctly in Production with Apache
I've been struggling with serving static files in a Django application deployed on Apache. Despite following numerous guides and suggestions, I'm still encountering 404 errors for my static files. Below are the relevant details of my setup and the issues I'm facing.
Environment:
Django Version: 3.0
Python Version: 3.8
Web Server: Apache2
OS: Ubuntu
Problem Description:
In development mode with DEBUG=True, the static files load correctly and I can see my React build. However, in production with DEBUG=False (or even with Debug=True), I encounter the following errors:
404 errors for JavaScript and CSS files
MIME type errors stating that the files are being served as text/html instead of their correct types
Errors in Browser Console:

GET https://www.myapp.com/static/js/main.a14a4a4b.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
Refused to execute script from 'https://www.myapp.com/static/js/main.a14a4a4b.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
Refused to apply style from 'https://www.myapp.com/static/css/main.868dfa48.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
GET https://www.myapp.com/favicon.png 404 (Not Found)
GET https://www.myapp.com/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.


Directory Structure:
Here's the structure of my staticfiles directory:
/var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles:
asset-manifest.json  css  favicon.png  index.html  js  logo192.png  logo512.png  manifest.json  media  robots.txt  sitemap.xml  static

/var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/css:
main.868dfa48.css  main.868dfa48.css.map

/var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/js:
main.a14a4a4b.js  main.a14a4a4b.js.LICENSE.txt  main.a14a4a4b.js.map

/var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/media:
MyAppSwap.7be50f5ecb7b614c38c9.png  eth.df265e367364f285053a1285ad8d418d.svg

/var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/static:
css  js  media

/var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/static/css:
main.868dfa48.css  main.868dfa48.css.map

/var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/static/js:
main.a14a4a4b.js  main.a14a4a4b.js.LICENSE.txt  main.a14a4a4b.js.map

/var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/static/media:
MyAppSwap.7be50f5ecb7b614c38c9.png  eth.df265e367364f285053a1285ad8d418d.svg
settings.py:


import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
REACT_APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myappswap', 'dex', 'build')


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(REACT_APP_DIR, "static"),
]

DEBUG = False


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            REACT_APP_DIR,
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

Apache Configuration:
default-ssl.conf:
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName www.myapp.com
        ServerAlias myapp.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/jmyapp

        WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/var/www/jmyapp/mysite_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup mysite
        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/jmyapp/mysite/wsgi.py

        Alias /robots.txt /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/robots.txt
        Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/favicon.png
        Alias /static/ /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/
        Alias /media/ /var/www/jmyapp/media/

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol -ALL +TLSv1.2
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem

        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            <Location "/geconame/">
                SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(localhost|www\.myapp\.com)$" ACAO=$0
                Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ACAO}e env=ACAO
                Header merge Vary Origin
            </Location>
        </IfModule>

        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/jmyapp>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/jmyapp/media>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/jmyapp/mysite>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
            </Files>
        </Directory>

        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
            nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
            downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

mysite.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.myapp.com
    ServerAlias myapp.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        <Location "/geconame/">
            SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(localhost|www\.myapp\.com)$" ACAO=$0
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ACAO}e env=ACAO
            Header merge Vary Origin
        </Location>
    </IfModule>

    WSGIDaemonProcess jmyapp python-path=/var/www/jmyapp/mysite_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup jmyapp
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/jmyapp/mysite/wsgi.py

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/favicon.png
    Alias /static/ /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles/
    Alias /media/ /var/www/jmyapp/media/

    <Directory /var/www/jmyapp>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/jmyapp/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/jmyapp/mysite>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

URLs Configuration:
main/urls.py:
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage

app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.mappage, name='mappage'),
    path('coins/<cryptoname>', views.coinspage, name='coinspage'),
    path('prices/<number>', views.prices, name='prices'),
    path('new_prices/<number>', views.new_prices, name='new_prices'),
    path('geconame/', views.get_coin, name='coin_name'),
    path('api/crypto-data/', views.crypto_data_api, name='crypto_data_api'),
    path('api/socialinfo/', views.socialinfo, name='socialinfo'),
    path('web3/tokenPrice/', views.token_price, name='token_price'),
    path('web3/dexSwap/', views.dex_swap, name='dex_swap'),
    path('web3/broadcastTransaction/', views.broadcast_transaction, name='broadcast_transaction'),
]

mysite/urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blogs.urls')),
    path('swap/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='swap'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

package.json:

"name": "dex",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "antd": "^5.1.5",
    "axios": "^1.2.3",
    "browserify-zlib": "^0.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.7.0",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "path-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "querystring-es3": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.6.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "stream-browserify": "^3.0.0",
    "url": "^0.11.3",
    "wagmi": "^0.10.11",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "web3": "^4.9.0",
    "yesno": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.2"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
}


Steps Taken:
Ensured file permissions are correct:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/jmyapp/staticfiles

Ran collectstatic to gather all static files:
python manage.py collectstatic

Restarted Apache:
sudo systemctl restart apache2

Verified that files exist in the correct directories.
Issue:
Even after all these steps, the static files are still not being served correctly in production. The browser is attempting to load them from the /static/ URL, but they are not found, resulting in 404 errors and MIME type issues. I even set
<BrowserRouter basename="/">

Questions:
Why are the static files not being found in production?
How can I resolve the MIME type issues?
Is there anything wrong with my Apache configuration or Django settings?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would suggest looking at the Apache logs themselves, maybe they hold a hint

What solved my issue was disabling and enabling the conf files making sure there were no errors. I installed whitenoise as well but in the end I think the conf files not actually being updated was what was giving me issues, took me way too long to figure that one out. Now I'm seeing slight css differences in production and in development
cracks fingesr

The ol' ~"forgot to save" / not working with current edits. brutal lmao
